# opengl es texture masking glow in shadow with glTexEnvi

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I'm trying to achieve the glowing of masked parts of a texture in the shadow like windows in the dark side of [this](http://images.wikia.com/memoryalpha/en/images/4/4b/USS_Enterprise-D,_These_Are_the_Voyages.jpg) using glTexEnvi.
But I guess im missing some big part. What is the right approach to render this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution. The drawback here is the double rendering, but i have my effect!

```
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_NORMALIZE);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

            // texture 0
            texture.bind(); // main texture
            draw();

            // texture 1
            gl.glColor4f(0,1,0,1); // desired color of the glow
            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING); // disable light for enabling glow in the shadow
            gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
            mask.bind();
            draw();

            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING); //enable light again
            gl.glColor4f(1,1,1,1); //restore color
```